# jmeter: need to perform x http requests each with 3 objects in body picked from a JSON extractor results per 3

Tags: jmeter

jmeter: need to perform x http requests each with 3 objects in body picked from a JSON extractor results per 3

I have an http request which returns JSON and extract my data from there.
This results to a list like 
[image]
which might hold 5, 8, 16 or 30, etc objects for example.
this means arti_1, arti_2, arti_3, etc
So far so good.

I need somehow and create x new http requests each one with 3 elements out from from the results.
I could put them all in a list.

For e.g. if list is {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, then I need 3 new http requests

- 1st holding a, b, c
- 2nd holding d, e, f
- 3rd holding g ,h

How should I apply that in the loop and counter?
Or should this be done in another way?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to your test plan
2. Use [__groovy function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to calculate required number of loops like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(Math.ceil((vars.get('arti_matchNr') as int)/3) as int,)}
   ```

   The expression above will create the required number of loops, i.e.:

   - 2 loops for 5 matches
   - 3 loops for 8 matches
   - 6 loops for 16 matches
   - etc. See [Mathematical Functions and Converting Data Types in Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mathematical-functions-and-converting-data-types-in-groovy) article for more information if needed
3. You can refer current Loop Controller's iteration as `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` in test elements or as `vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx`)` in a Groovy script in order to build your request data depending on current loop value. Unfortunately we cannot provide exact steps with regards to how to do this as we have no idea about how you're gonna use the values in the HTTP Requests.